# Text[] using Graphics

Tags: graphics, text

```
Graphics[{
  Text[
       Style["Jean", 14, Bold, "Helvetica", Black, 
    TextAlignment -> Right],{1, 1}],

  Text[
       Style["Claude", 10, "Helvetica", Bold, Black, 
       TextAlignment -> Right], {19, .8}]},

 PlotRange -> {{0, 21}, {0, 2}}, ImageSize -> 300,
 Method -> {"ShrinkWrap" -> True},
 ImagePadding -> 2,
 ImageMargins -> 0]
```

[image]

**Now if i just try to add a small `Rectangle[]`, the `Text[]` disappear.**

```
Graphics[{
  Rectangle[{18, 0}, {20, 2}],
  Text[
       Style["Jean", 14, Bold, "Helvetica", Black, 
    TextAlignment -> Right],{1, 1}],

  Text[
       Style["Claude", 10, "Helvetica", Bold, Black, 
       TextAlignment -> Right], {19, .8}]},

 PlotRange -> {{0, 21}, {0, 2}}, ImageSize -> 300,
 Method -> {"ShrinkWrap" -> True},
 ImagePadding -> 2,
 ImageMargins -> 0]
```

[image]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you take out `Method -> {"ShrinkWrap" -> True}` it works as I think you expect.

Comment: +1 for pointing this out. I realized after I posted my answer that I didn't know why the leftmost part of the image was disappearing. Thanks!

Comment: @FJRA,Thank You it works, can you explain ? I use the "ShrinkWrap" to export with any borders. In this case I would like the text on a transparent BackGround.

Comment: To export with a transparent background you can add the `Background -> None` option: `Export["file.png", g, Background -> None]`

Answer (score 5):

The text doesn't disappear, you're just not seeing it. Try the following mod to your code:

```
Graphics[{Red, Rectangle[{18, 0}, {20, 2}], 
Text[Style["Jean", 14, Red, Bold, "Helvetica", Black, 
TextAlignment -> Right], {1, 1}], 
Text[Style["Claude", 10, "Helvetica", Bold, Black, 
TextAlignment -> Right], {19, .8}]}, 
PlotRange -> {{0, 21}, {0, 2}},
Frame -> Automatic,
ImageSize->Large,
ImageSize -> 300, Method -> {"ShrinkWrap" -> True}, 
ImagePadding -> 2, ImageMargins -> 0]
```

Here's what you'll see:

[image]

So Claude is just hidden by your black rectangle. Jean is far to the left of your rectangle.

Comment: Thank You but I don`t want the frame. `Frame->None` and I am back in Trouble.

Comment: As FJRA suggested, you should delete `Method ->{"ShrinkWrap" -> True}`